# How can I optimize this subquery as join?

Tags: sql, postgresql, optimization, postgis

I've noticed that running this subquery

> SELECT
>   ST_Area(ST_Union(ST_Transform(ST_Intersection((SELECT poly1.the_geom from poly1 WHERE poly1.polygon_type='P'),poly2.the_geom),3857)))
>
> AS area_of_P
>   FROM poly1, poly2

is significantly slower than running this join

> SELECT 
>   ST_AREA(ST_Union(ST_Transform(ST_Intersection(poly1.the_geom,poly2.the_geom),3857)))
>
> AS area_of_poly
>
> FROM poly2
>
> LEFT JOIN poly1 on st_intersects(poly1.the_geom,poly2.the_geom)
>
> WHERE poly2.polygon_type='P'

However, I need to expand upon this second joined version to return more columns, each with the area of a given polygon type calculated, i.e.

> SELECT
>   ST_Area(ST_Union(ST_Transform(ST_Intersection((SELECT poly1.the_geom from poly1 WHERE poly1.polygon_type='P'),poly2.the_geom),3857))) 
>   AS area_of_P,
>
> ST_Area(ST_Union(ST_Transform(ST_Intersection((SELECT poly1.the_geom from poly1 WHERE poly1.polygon_type='S'),poly2.the_geom),3857))) 
>   AS area_of_S
>
> FROM poly1, poly2

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this.

```
SELECT ST_AREA(ST_Union(ST_Transform(ST_Intersection(poly1.the_geom,poly2.the_geom),3857)))

AS area_of_poly

FROM poly2

LEFT JOIN poly1 on st_intersects(poly1.the_geom,poly2.the_geom)

WHERE poly2.polygon_type IN ( 'P', 'S' )
```

Edit:

```
SELECT ST_AREA(ST_Union(ST_Transform(ST_Intersection(ps.the_geom,poly2.the_geom),3857))) AS area_of_P,
       ST_AREA(ST_Union(ST_Transform(ST_Intersection(ss.the_geom,poly2.the_geom),3857))) AS area_of_S
FROM poly2
JOIN poly1 ps ON poly2.polygon_type = 'P' AND st_intersects(ps.the_geom,poly2.the_geom)
JOIN poly1 ss ON poly2.polygon_type = 'S' AND st_intersects(ss.the_geom,poly2.the_geom)
```

Comment: Sorry, I should have made this clearer.  I want to return two columns.  One being the area of polygon type 'P', the other being the area of polygon type 'S'.

Comment: Works exactly as I need it to.  Thanks Brett.